# MySQL (exploding/matching array)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode

Question1:

**MySQL table**

**id | array**
1  | 1,2,3
2  | 2
3  | 2,3
4  | 4,5,6

```
$_GET['id'] = 2;
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `array` ??? '$_GET[id]'");
```

In this step, I want to run through the **entire** array and see if it matches with the $_GET['id'], so it should output:

ids: 1,2,3

Question2:

**MySQL table**

**id | array**
1  | 4,5,6
2  | 3,4,7

```
$_GET['id'] = 4;
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `array` ??? '$_GET[id]'");
```

In this step, I **only** want to match against the first element in the array, so it should output:

id: 4

I can only think of using PHP to do this, but I'd rather do all that just within the MySQL query, if that is even possible.

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
{
    $elements = explode(',', $b['array']);
    foreach($elements as $element)
    {
        if($element == $_GET['id'])
        {
            echo $b['id'].'<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
{
    $array = $b['array'];

    if(in_array($_GET['id'], $array))
    {
        echo $b['id'].'<br />';
    }
}
```

that would look just awful.

Comment: normalize your db schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure in the DB is not optimal for querying the way you want it.

For the first question:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE array LIKE '%,$_GET[id],%' OR array LIKE '$_GET[id],%' OR array LIKE '%,$_GET[id]' OR array = '$_GET[id]'");
```

For the second:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id, SUBSTR(array, 1, POSITION(',' IN array) - 1) AS array FROM table WHERE array LIKE '$_GET[id],%' OR array = '$_GET[id]'");
```

As you can see, these queries aren't pretty, but they'll do what you want.

Comment: What about in the first question, when the value is at the beginning of the string? It won't match (doesn't have a , before it). Also don't forget to *sanitise your input*!!

Comment: hey, thanks! why, how else would you structure it? i just thought it would be easier to save an array for certain tasks.

Comment: @Blair: The query matches if the number starts the array, or is the only element in the array.

@user317005: You should save each array value as a separate row, like `create table table_name (id int, value int)` each id would have multiple rows, but it's much easier to do queries.

Comment: Sorry, for whatever reason I didn't notice the OR's in there, so I only saw the first `LIKE`.
@user317005 As jmz says, you are effectively storing a MANY-MANY relationship (each 'item' can have many 'values' and each 'value' can belong to many 'items'). There are plenty of articles around for how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

That you can/should structure your database differently has already been mentioned (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). But....

See [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

> mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
>         -> 2

e.g.

```
<?php
$mysql = init();    
bar($mysql, 1);
bar($mysql, 2);
bar($mysql, 3);
bar($mysql, 4);


function bar($mysql, $x) {
  $sql_x = mysql_real_escape_string($x, $mysql);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, foo FROM soTest WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$sql_x', foo)", $mysql) or die(mysql_error());

  echo "$x:\n";
  while( false!==($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) ) {
    echo $row['id'], ' ', $row['foo'], "\n";
  }
  echo "----\n";
}

function init() {
  $mysql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly') or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('test', $mysql) or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soTest (id int auto_increment, foo varchar(64), primary key(id))', $mysql) or die(__LINE__.' '.mysql_error());
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO soTest (foo) VALUES ('1,2,3'), ('2,4'), ('3'), ('2,3'), ('1,2')", $mysql) or die(__LINE__.' '.mysql_error());
  return $mysql;
}
```

prints

```
1:
1 1,2,3
5 1,2
----
2:
1 1,2,3
2 2,4
4 2,3
5 1,2
----
3:
1 1,2,3
3 3
4 2,3
----
4:
2 2,4
----
```

MySQL can't use indices to perform this search, i.e. the query results in a full table scan, see [Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)

---

edit:
For your second question you only have to change the WHERE-clause to
`WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$sql_x', foo)=1`

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you should be able to use:

Question 1:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE array REGEXP '(^|,)?(,|$)';
// Match either the start of the string, or a , then the query value, then either a , or the end of the string
```

Question 2:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE array REGEXP '^?(,|$)';
// Match the start of the string, then the query value, then either a , or the end of the string
```

Where `?` is replaced with your `$_GET` value.
No idea on the performance of this.

Answer (score 0):

**First One:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE array LIKE '$_GET[id],%' OR array LIKE '%,$_GET[id],%' OR array LIKE '%,$_GET[id]' OR array = '$_GET[id]
```

**Second One:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE array LIKE '$_GET[id],%' OR array = '$_GET[id]
```

Explanation:

- `'$_GET[id],%'` will match, if array is start with `$_GET[id]`
- `'%,$_GET[id],%'` will match, if `$_GET[id]` is between any two of array items
- `'%,$_GET[id]'` will match, if array is end with `$_GET[id]`
- array = `'$_GET[id]'` match, if the array contains only one item equal to `$_GET[id]`

Comment: '23,4' LIKE '3', its not true. '3,4' like '3' its true.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to bring your database to the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), e. g.

```
CREATE TABLE t_master (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE t_array (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    master_id INT NOT NULL,
    value INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_array_master_id FOREIGN KEY (master_id) REFERENCES t_master (id)
);
```

Then you can find records in `t_master` that have a specific `value` with

```
$q = 'SELECT m.* ' .
    'FROM t_master AS m INNER JOIN t_array AS a ON a.master_id = m.id ' .
    "WHERE a.value = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'], $db) . "' " .
    'GROUP BY m.id';
```

The most important advantage is that if you have a lot of values, you can add an index to find them much faster:

```
ALTER TABLE t_array ADD INDEX idx_value (value);
```

A less evident, but not the last advantage is that your queries become more logical and structured.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't normalise your schema (which is the best option:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE ','+array+',' LIKE '%,$_GET[id],%'
```

But if you need to access the records by id, then you really should normalise